# Complimentary filter for Xsens sensor

Tags: python, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am trying to fuse Xsens MTi-20 sensor gyro with accelerometer using complementary filter, calculated angle looks okay, at least i think so, but the problem is that when sensor in not moved values for roll and pitch are increasing at a steady rate.
The data output frequency is 100 Hz, so as dt im using- 0,01
Gyro data unit is rad/sec and accelerometer data is in m/s^2.
Here is snippet from complementary part from my code:

```
DEG_TO_RAD = math.pi / 180
RAD_TO_DEG = 180 / math.pi
start_time = time.time()

accumulated_gyr_pitch = 0
accumulated_gyr_roll = 0

#complimentary filter
def complimentary_filter(acc, gyr, dt, alpha):
    global accumulated_gyr_pitch
    global accumulated_gyr_roll

    angle_acc_pitch = math.atan2(acc[0], math.sqrt(acc[1]**2 + acc[2]**2)) * RAD_TO_DEG
    angle_acc_roll = math.atan2(acc[1], math.sqrt(acc[0]**2 + acc[2]**2)) * RAD_TO_DEG

    accumulated_gyr_pitch += gyr[1] * dt 
    accumulated_gyr_roll += gyr[0] * dt

    # radians to degrees
    accumulated_gyr_pitch_deg = accumulated_gyr_pitch * RAD_TO_DEG
    accumulated_gyr_roll_deg = accumulated_gyr_roll * RAD_TO_DEG

    pitch = (1 - alpha) * (accumulated_gyr_pitch_deg) + (alpha * angle_acc_pitch)
    roll = (1 - alpha) * (accumulated_gyr_roll_deg) + (alpha * angle_acc_roll)
    return roll, pitch

def apply_filters(data_buffer):
    alpha = 0.25
    dt = 0.01
    current_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = current_time - start_time

    with open('filtered_data.txt', 'w') as filtered_file:
        while keep_reading_data:
            if len(data_buffer) > 0:
                acc, gyr, mag, elapsed_time = data_buffer.pop(0)
                roll, pitch= complimentary_filter(acc, gyr, dt, alpha)
                print(f'Roll: {roll:.2f}, Pitch: {pitch:.2f}, Time: {elapsed_time:.2f}')
                filtered_file.write(f'Roll: {roll:.2f}, Pitch: {pitch:.2f}, Time: {elapsed_time:.2f}\n')
                filtered_file.flush()
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

So far i had not find solution for this problem, so i hope for your help!
I also added a graphic to show the problem more clearly:
[Compl.filt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlmKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a small gyroscope bias and your choice of gain.  Try adjusting the gain.  For example set `alpha` to 1.  This will force the filter to only use the accelerometer.  Confirm that the angles are stable, then slowly reduce the gain (e.g. 0.999) until stability is lost.

Lastly, you can save time troubleshooting and validate your setup using an independent algorithm to process the data.  For example https://imuengine.io/engine/ .  The same site has sample datasets as well.